# Android import Transformer for using that for Loader

Tags: android

in [this link](http://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2017/03/17/keeping-state-rxjava.html) i read that to using RxJava on phone rotation and save state, but i have simple problem on import `Transformer` on this class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.reactivestreams.Subscription;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.subjects.BehaviorSubject;

public class RxLoader<T> extends Loader<T> {
    private final Observable<T> observable;
    private final BehaviorSubject<T> cache = BehaviorSubject.create();

    private Subscription subscription;

    private RxLoader(Context context, Observable<T> observable) {
        super(context);
        this.observable = observable;
    }

    public static <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> compose(AppCompatActivity activity, int id) {
        return observable -> create(activity, id, observable);
    }


    public static <T> Observable<T> create(AppCompatActivity activity, int id,
                                           Observable<T> observable) {
        LoaderManager loaderManager = activity.getSupportLoaderManager();

        CreateLoaderCallback<T> createLoaderCallback =
                new CreateLoaderCallback<>(activity, observable);
        loaderManager.initLoader(id, null, createLoaderCallback);

        RxLoader<T> rxLoader = (RxLoader<T>) loaderManager.getLoader(id);
        return rxLoader.cache.asObservable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        super.onStartLoading();
        subscription = observable.subscribe(cache::onNext);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        super.onReset();
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    private static class CreateLoaderCallback<T>
            implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<T> {

        private final Context context;
        private final Observable<T> observable;

        public CreateLoaderCallback(Context context, Observable<T> observable) {
            this.context = context;
            this.observable = observable;
        }

        @Override
        public Loader<T> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            return new RxLoader<>(context, observable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<T> loader, T data) { }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<T> loader) { }
    }
}
```

problem is in this part of class:

```
public static <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> compose( ...
```

Comment: What rxjava version have you imported?

Comment: @azizbekian they are `compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'`

Answer (score 0):

The code you have imported most possibly is implemented with RxJava 1.

You have two options:

- Import RxJava 1 instead of RxJava 2
- Convert existing code to RxJava 2's [ObserverTransformer](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/ObservableTransformer.java)

Comment: the date of document is  `Mar 17, 2017` i want to use latest version of rxJava library, could you help me on this topic `http://stackoverflow.com/q/42887943/6596724`